# Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages , When I Install php on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, 16.04, package-management

Why I see this problem when i want to install php on ubuntu 16.04 and how can I fix it ?

the problem is this : 
[image: Click To See The Image]

I have tried :

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install -f
apt-get clean
apt-get autoclean
apt-get autoremove
dpkg --configure -a
```

And there is no problem with doing these commands !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: I tried these solutions but the problem is still the same :(

Answer (score 5):

You can use Aptitude to automatically fix the broken packages.

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude

sudo aptitude install libmodule libapache2-mod-php
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install PHP7 to fixt it

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php-7.0
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0-cli php7.0-common libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0 php7.0-mysql php7.0-fpm php7.0-curl php7.0-gd php7.0-bz2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the required PHP modules dependencies before you run PHP7.3 successful.

```
sudo apt install php7.3-mysql php7.3-curl php7.3-json php7.3-cgi php7.3-xsl
```